# Slim/Twig removing apostrophe and text after it?

Tags: php, twig, slim, html-escape-characters

So I am using twig and slim along with your average PHP to do some pagination. Pre-pagination, slim was not removing spaces/apostrophes from links, but now it is. Any help is appreciated and hopefully it isn't something stupid obvious.

Relevant code is displayed below. Ask me if you need more.

**route**

```
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT * FROM businesses ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");

//Display records fetched from database.
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
  $name = $row['name'];
  $link_bprofile = $app->urlFor('business.profile', array('name' => $name));
  $link_adminedit = $app->urlFor('admin.business.edit', array('business' => $name));
  $link_admindelete = $app->urlFor('admin.business.delete', array('business' => $name));

  $endResult .= '<tr>';
  $endResult .=  "<td>[<a href='$link_bprofile'>Profile</a>]</td>";
  $endResult .=  "<td>$name</td>";
  $endResult .=  "<td>[<a href='$link_adminedit'>Edit</a>]</td>";
  $endResult .=  "<td>[<a href='$link_admindelete'>Remove</a>]</td>";
  $endResult .=  "<td>$name</td>";
  $endResult .= '</tr>';
}
## End displaying Records ##

$app->render('/business/all.php', [
  'businesses' => $businesses,
  'business' => $app->business,
  'pagination' => $endResult,
  'links' => $app->business->pagination($total_pages, $item_per_page, $currentPage, $page_url)
]);
```

**view**

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
<div class="col-md-12 content">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"> Businesses </div>
        <div class="panel-body text-center">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="text-align: center;" name="businesses_tab" id="businesses_tab">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;"></th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Upvotes</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Downvotes</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Reviews</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
              {{ pagination | raw }}
                </tbody>
            </table>
          <ul class="pagination">
            {{ links | raw }}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I did some more reviewing and found out something interesting; Slim is outputting the link (when viewed as plain text) as "/dev/website/public/b/McDonald's", but the link itself is being viewed without the apostrophe and "s". This helps, but I still cannot find a way to solve this.

Comment: Can you clearly mention what your question is? I think its not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: @Subash When a print out all of the information from my database, it displays the name correctly on the page but the link for profiles is removing the apostrophe and any text after it

Comment: Take a look at what `urlFor()` does exactly and try to debug it.

Comment: @DeDee I updated my post at the end so please check that out... also I did look it up: "The Slim applications' urlFor() method lets you dynamically create URLs for a named route so that, were a route pattern to change, your URLs would update automatically without breaking your application. " - quoted from the official slim documentation

Comment: If there's a problem with links in a specific part of your application, you can use oldschool debugging, simply backup the file that defines `urlFor()` and edit original `urlFor()` adding your own logging function whenever the function passes or processes the variable holding the name, then you should see where exactly it loses the apostrophe. You can use `echo`, `fwrite()` or whatever you prefer. It often can lead to enlightenment of something obvious missed in other place.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an easy solution to my problem... take the business id as a parameter instead of its name. This makes it to where the link won't be issued for escaping characters or anything of that sort.

Thanks to all of those to gave good information and tried to help. :D